# When I run k-Means by Mahout,always show this tip

Tags: java, hadoop, k-means, hadoop2, mahout

code:

```
hadoop jar /home/xnz/local/opt/apache-mahout-distribution-0.13.0/mahout-integration-0.13.0.jar \
    org.apache.mahout.clustering.conversion.InputDriver \
    -i /user/root/ -o /user/root/input/seqfile
```

error tip:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    org/apache/commons/cli2/OptionException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    org.apache.commons.cli2.OptionException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:430)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
    ...4 more
``
```

Comment: why don't you use mahout command `bin/mahout kmeans <args>`?

Answer (score 1):

It is clear from the exception. You are missing the `org.apache.commons.cli2` Jar in your Classpath.

Comment: But the current release is CLI 1.4. From  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/ .Thanks.